# How to make effective permament rubble in a voxel game made in Unity3D?

Tags: unity, optimization, voxels

I'm working on a **semi-voxel** game, and I already optimized the voxel structures' meshes by combining and chunking them.

When I destroy a voxel, I spawn a **low poly voxel fragment**, with a rigidbody and a collider. And then I add an explosion force.

Even if I turn off rigidbodies when they stop moving, or disable overall physics, the **amount of separate meshes** to render causes a **huge fps loss** after a few destroyed voxels.

How could I achieve permanent rubbles?

[image]

Comment: Is each piece of rubble a different shape, or do they share a mesh that could be batched or instanced?

Comment: Back in the day they were different, now I use the same, and on their materials I enabled GPU instancing.

Comment: Have you used the frame debugger at all to see if they are actually being instanced and share draw calls?

Comment: In UpdateDepthTexture there are 313 entries and there are some fragments, and they are instanced.
But in UpdateDepthNormalsTexture there are 3134 entries, lots of fragments and none of them are instanced.
In Drawing there are 3500 entires, lots of fragments and only a few are instanced.
Why?

Comment: The frame debugger can answer that question for you quite directly, depending on the version of Unity you are using. For more information here https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/GPUInstancing.html and here https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/DrawCallBatching.html